# pythonのgoogletransモジュールをオフラインでインストールしたい

Tags: python, python3, pip

オフラインの環境で、googlrtransの3.0.0をインストールする必要がでました。
依存関係がありそうで、./source　というフォルダに以下をダウンロードしました。
OSはLinux mint20.3になります。

googletrans-3.0.0.tar.gz
hstspreload-2020.3.4.tar.gz
httpx-0.13.3.tar.gz
setuptools-63.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
sniffio-1.2.0.tar.gz

以下のコマンドを実行しました。

```
pip install --no-index --find-links=./source googletrans
```

そうすると、以下のようなエラーメッセージが表示されます。

このsetuptoolsのバージョンが問題なのかと思い、種々のバージョンを入れ替えて、入れているのですが、エラーメッセージが変わらず、どうにも弱りました。
何が問題か、考えられることはあるでしょうか。
何卒、よろしくお願い申し上げます。

```
Looking in links: ./source
Processing ./source/googletrans-3.0.0.tar.gz
Processing ./source/httpx-0.13.3.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: certifi in /home/akira/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-2020.11/envs/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from httpx==0.13.3->googletrans) (2020.6.20)
Processing ./source/hstspreload-2020.3.4.tar.gz
Processing ./source/sniffio-1.2.0.tar.gz
Installing build dependencies ... error
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: /home/akira/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-2020.11/envs/venv/bin/python /home/akira/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-2020.11/envs/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-g1s1ui2q/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: --no-index --find-links ./source -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel
cwd: None
Complete output (4 lines):
Looking in links: ./source
Processing ./source/setuptools-63.1.0-py3-none-any.whl
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement wheel (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for wheel
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/akira/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-2020.11/envs/venv/bin/python /home/akira/.pyenv/versions/anaconda3-2020.11/envs/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-g1s1ui2q/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: --no-index --find-links ./source -- 'setuptools>=40.8.0' wheel Check the logs for full command output.
```

Comment: ちなみに、この質問を英語で投げたところ、Your post appears to contain code that is not properly formatted as code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.　というエラーが出て投稿できませんでした。

Comment: pyenv+venv+anaconda で環境構築されているのでしょうか？ また「pip install」でインストールするということはanacondaで仮想環境を作成されているということでしょうか？

Comment: pyenvのcondaで仮想環境名をvenvにしています。そこが少しややこしく映っているかもしれません。おっしゃる通り、anacondaで仮想環境を構築しています。

Comment: では環境構築はpyenv+anacondaということですね？ 念のため確認ですが、今回モジュールをインストールしようとしている仮想環境でcondaとpipの併用はしていない、ということで良いですね？

Comment: ご連絡が遅くなってすみません。仮想環境では基本的にcondaですが、一部pipでインストールしているものもあります。例えば、今回のgoogletransはcondaだと2.4.0のバージョンになってしまいますが、4.0.0をインストールしたいためにpipを使いたいと考えております。

Comment: condaとpipを同じ環境で使用すると不具合が起きることがあるようです。新たに仮想環境を作成してすべてpipでインストールしてみてはどうでしょうか？